# Is there an analogous Gibbs phenomena to approximating sinusoidal but with polynomial terms?

Tags: statistics, polynomials, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, machine-learning

I was trying to approximate a sine curve with a finite number of polynomials terms using linear regression (or the pseudo-inverse). I construct a Vandermonde matrix (or a Kernel polynomial feature matrix) and then solve the linear system (usually using the pseudo-inverse):

$$ y = \Phi(x)w$$

then I try to visualize the solution. For low degree polynomials the approximation seems fine but eventually when the degree of the polynomial is pretty high, there is a weird funky bit at the edge:

[image]

This reminded me of [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) where at discontinuities there seems to be high oscillations near the jump. I know that Gibbs phenomena happens with a finite sum of Fourier series. However, this empirical observation really made me wonder. Is this the reason the edge of the approximation looks strange?

Also from a statistics/machine learning point of view it seems clear that if the solution is not regularized, then a high complexity model should overfit to noise. However, in this model there is no noise. Therefore, I was not quite sure what was going on and was wondering what it was.

Thus, my question is, is there a Gibbs phenomena for approximating sinusoidal with a finite number of polynomial terms? If yes, then what is it and what are its details?

---

Another observation that I found odd is that the high oscillation/jump only happened at the right discontinuity. I am not sure why that is but I thought it was quite puzzling.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it's a bad idea to use interpolation polynomials for  equally spaced points as approximations.  See [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).

On the other hand, there are much better ways to get good polynomial approximations to continuous functions on an interval.  See [Chebyshev series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#As_a_basis_set) and [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm).

Comment: Imagine I want to keep using the form of polynomials in my original post/question and the pseudo-inverse as the interpolation/learning algorithm. Would just choosing the points randomly in the interval instead of equally spaced help avoid this phenomena?

Comment: What is a good way to sample data points on an interval as to avoid Runge's phenomenon but have a deterministic sampling scheme?

Comment: You might try [Chebyshev nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes).

Comment: is it true that no matter how we sample the data points, we will **always** experience Runge's phenomenon to some extent?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Convergence_properties).  For any table of nodes there is a continuous function where the sequence of interpolating polynomials diverges.  However, for Chebyshev nodes and an **absolutely continuous** function it converges uniformly.