# Why is it that Runge's phenomenon gives rise to oscillations at the edges and not in other locations?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, interpolation

Why is it that Runge's phenomenon gives rise to oscillations at the edges and not in other locations? What I don't understand is why the oscillations arises at the edges and not somewhere else? What seems weird to me is that the phenomenon seems to arise due to **the sampling scheme** of the interpolation points (or at least that is how its emphasized in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge's_phenomenon) article). Thus, if its a problem due to sampling why is it that the oscillations concentrate at the edges and not at other places?

I'd love to be able to go through the proof myself but with a weak background in basic analysis makes me doubt my capabilities of this. Therefore, intuitive/conceptual explanations are probably the ones I will most likely understand best, though I don't want to discourage people that want to provide a in depth answer, though don't forget to try to provide a high level one too if its not too much to ask.

Comment: This is an good question which is also of interest of educators as Runge's function is a standard example in many entry level textbooks.

Comment: If you'll look at the Runge example again, you'll notice that the function under consideration has poles in the complex plane. The oscillations you're seeing are the polynomial interpolant's desperate attempt to keep up as the magnitude of the argument nears the magnitude of the nearest pole.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician not sure if this a tangential question but what I don't understand say if I want to approximate a sine with polynomials over $[0,1]$, why do the polynomials go crazy at the edges of the interval? How is the related to the poles you mentioned?

Comment: Could you clarify your question on the sine? [I don't see any problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU7hc.png) if I try to approximate $\sin x$ with a degree-20 polynomial over $[0,1]$.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician yes I can clarify. I had in mind $sin(2 \pi x ) = y_{target}$ with polynomials of increasing degree (try 100). You usually get a weird crazy bump on the edges with least squares. Look at this question I asked earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513148/is-there-an-analogous-gibbs-phenomena-to-approximating-sinusoidal-but-with-polyn

Comment: Ah, that's a much deeper question that is related, but distinct, from Runge's example. I'll see if I can write an answer to your other question later, but the executive summary is that you should use a point distribution where the points cluster near the ends of the interval (e.g. Chebyshev points).

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician oh interesting, I didn't think it was different from Runge's phenomenon (clearly from the answer I received to the other question). Now I am confused about the difference, are there two different phenomenons we are talking about?

Answer (score 6):

> ...intuitive/conceptual explanations are probably the ones I will most likely understand best...

I guess seeing is believing:

[image: Runge in the complex plane]

These are plots of the real part, imaginary part, and magnitude of the Runge function $\dfrac1{1+25z^2}$ and its $n$-point polynomial interpolant over the points $z_k=\dfrac{2k}{n}-1;\quad k=1,\dots,n$, evaluated over complex arguments.

For reference, here's how the Runge function itself looks like in the complex plane:

[image: real part, imaginary part, and magnitude of the Runge function]

Notice the poles jutting out of the surface. These two poles are precisely the reason why interpolating this function with polynomials is difficult; polynomials themselves don't ever have poles, so the poor polynomial interpolant oscillates grandly in a pathetic attempt to emulate the poles of the rational function it is trying to approximate. Both the functions are analytic (holomorphic for the polynomial interpolant; meromorphic for the Runge function), so any bad behavior in the complex plane gets passed along to the real line:

[image: cross-section over the real line]

---

For those who want to play around with this in *Mathematica*:

```
Manipulate[GraphicsRow[
           Table[Plot3D[Evaluate[{f[1/(1 + 25 (x + I y)^2)], 
                        f[InterpolatingPolynomial[
                          Table[With[{xx = 2 i/n - 1}, {xx, 1/(1 + 25 xx^2)}],
                                {i, 0, n}], x + I y]]}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
                 BoxRatios -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> None, Mesh -> False, 
                 PlotLabel -> f, PlotRange -> {-3/2, 3/2}, 
                 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[3/4], Opacity[1/2]}], {f, {Re, Im, Abs}}]],
          {n, 2, 30, 1}]
```

Comment: I know this a super noob question but I'm going to ask it anyway (you already knew from my question that I'm not good with beyond this type of maths). Anyway, why do polynomials not have poles? This seems to be key so I had to ask.

Comment: Rational functions in general have poles. A *pole* corresponds to where the denominator of a rational function becomes zero, which makes the value of the rational function infinite. Can you think of *finite* values where a polynomial would become infinite?

Comment: ah! I see. So the issue is that in finite points polynomials aren't infinite. Of course no wonder they have difficulties approximating that. Though I'm still puzzled about the "oscillation" part. Does the oscillation part only happen close to the poles and close to the edges of the interval where the target function is defined? Why? I guess my confusion is perhaps not that poles are weird (which is now more clear thanks to you) but that equidistant samples lead to oscillation...at the edges!? Why not at every point or something like equidistant somehow trickles an effect to the edges.

Comment: That's two different phenomena colluding with each other to produce disastrous results, in fact: the presence of poles like I described in this answer, and that equispaced abscissae are in general a poor choice of interpolation points. But again, a detailed answer to that might have to be written by me at a much later date.

Comment: If you can't wait for my answer, I would recommend that you read [Trefethen's book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=h80N5JHm-u4C&pg=PA95) or [these](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9045(91)90090-W) [two](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/mythspaper.pdf) papers.

Comment: I am still a bit confused about Runge's Phenomena (probably cuz I don't have much experience beyond basic analysis), but what exactly is the source of Runge's phenomena? Right now I am trying to understand if the exponential bound on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) due to bad conditioning of pseudo-inverse or basis for the Vandermonde matrix or the sampling scheme or all 3 or just a few. For example, if I kept equidistant sampling points but changed the basis, would the exponential bound still exist and would the condition number improve?

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician just out of curiosity, if we changed to Hermite polynomials, would we still have the same issue as in Runge's phenomena that the error bound would be exponential something like $M_n \frac{h^n}{4n}$ where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial, $h$ is equi-distance and $M_n$ upper bound on the nth derivative?