# What is a good way to sample data points on an interval as to avoid Runge's phenomenon but have a deterministic sampling scheme?

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, numerical-methods, machine-learning, approximation-theory

I recently asked:

[Is there an analogous Gibbs phenomena to approximating sinusoidal but with polynomial terms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513148/is-there-an-analogous-gibbs-phenomena-to-approximating-sinusoidal-but-with-polyn)

because I noticed that at the edges, polynomial interpolation of equidistance points goes crazy. I want to avoid this and sample in a different way. Any way that **is deterministic** but avoid these explosions at the edges would be fantastic!

What is a good method to sample point as to avoid Runge's phenomenon In my particular case I am especially interested when only a few points are sampled, like 12, so answers addressing this point would be fantastic!

Comment: check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes

Answer (score 2):

To sample $n+1$ points in $[-1,1]$ you can use the roots of the $(n+1)$-th grade Chebyshev polynomial. So you'll minimize the norm infinity over $[-1,1]$ of $\prod_{i=0}^n (x-x_i)$ among all possible sets of $n+1$ nodes. For a general interval $[a,b]$ you just need to do an affine transformation, that is, given $x_0,\ldots,x_n$ which are the roots of $T_{n+1}$ (which all lay in $[-1,1]$), take $y_0,\ldots,y_n \in [a,b]$ as
$$y_i=\alpha x_i+\beta,$$
with $\alpha,\beta$ such that $a=\alpha \cdot (-1)+\beta$ and $b=\alpha \cdot 1+\beta$.

By the way, the $T_n$ polynomials satisfy the recursion
$$T_0(x)=1,\quad T_1(x)=x, \quad T_n(x)=2x \cdot T_{n-1}(x)-T_{n-2}(x),$$
and their roots are for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$x_k=\cos\left(\frac{2k-1}{2n} \pi\right),\quad k=1,2,\ldots,n.$$

Comment: interesting, so tried it using about 12 data points. Is this Chebyshev nodes sampling method less effective as the degree of the polynomial increases? Is there a condition relating the degree of the polynomial that is approximating the samples vs the number of samples that I need so that the approximation to the true function doesn't suck?

Comment: also do u have an intuition (since I lack the background to probably understand the full proof) of why such such sampling method helps?

Comment: it seems that sampling the points also changes the condition number of $X^T X$. Fascinating! Do you know why? It nearly seems like magic.

Comment: is it true that no matter how we sample the data points, we will **always** experience Runge's phenomenon to some extent?

Comment: Actually, it is not. For Runge's function ($f(x)=\tfrac 1 {1+25x^2}$) Chebyshev interpolation gets better and reduces oscilation of $P_n(x)$ as $n$ gets bigger. Moreover, $P_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$, and even more $||f-P_n||_{\infty,[-1,1]} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The mathematical background is related to the minimization property I mentioned before. Anyway, the intuition is that this method tends to pick many points very close to each other near the borders of the interval of interpolation, which is where Runge's phenomenon have place, and they get more sparse towards the center of the interval.

Comment: Chebyshev, Chebyshev, he's our man. If his nodes can't do it, nobody's can!

Comment: Let's call that #mnemonics (?)

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum ah! Thats interesting. Is there a way to characterize the functions that give rise to increasing degree of polynomial leads to better rate of approximation? 

What I've observed empirically is that when I approximate a sine curve with 11,12,13,14 points with Chebyshev, the increasing degree actually seems to increase the error of a "test set" (an approximation I guess to the integral in the interval $[-1,1]$).